# ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file

Tags: java

Meu projeto estava funcionando normalmente. Após reiniciar minha máquina, ao executá-lo pela IDE retorna o seguinte:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file Principal$9
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at Principal.main(Principal.java:707)
```

Alguém sabe por que esse erro ocorre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualizei a versão do JDK onde resolveu o problema.

Comment: Que erro bizarro.

Answer (score 2):

[*Incompatible magic value*](https://techhelpkb.com/java-incompatible-magic-value/) acontece quando uma classe foi corrompida de alguma maneira (e.g., o download de algum .class falhou ou o compilador / gerador de bytecodes fez algo que não deveria). Eu já vi isso acontecer algumas vezes em projetos Eclipse (que usam um compilador incremental) e / ou em projetos com Javassist, ASM, etc.

A classe começar com o byte 0 (ao invés de `CAFEBABE`) geralmente implica que um download falhou ou o compilador não fez o que deveria e criou um arquivo `.class` vazio.

A solução desse tipo de problema geralmente passa por limpar o cache de classes, verificar a integridade de qualquer classe que você tenha feito download (e.g., comparar o *checksum*), limpar e construir o projeto novamente e rever qualquer parte da *stack* que esteja manipulando *bytecode* (compilador, ferramentas que geram bytecode dinâmico, etc).